# Cannot read property "dispatcher" of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have some problems with making a Discord bot while creating the music module. It uses `ytdl-core` and `ffmpeg`.
Here is the problematic line:

```
if server.dispatcher server.dispatcher.end();
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot read property "dispatcher" of undefined.

Can someone help me?

```
// Constants, variables and functions
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const YTDL = require('ytdl-core');
const clientprefix = "//";
const opusscript = require('opusscript');
const moderatorprefix = "> ";
// Functions and variables
var errorEmbedCreate = function(des) {
  return({embed: {color: 16711680, title: ":x: Error",description: des}});
}

var warningEmbedCreate = function(des) {
  return({embed: {color: 16763904, title: ":warning: Warning",description: des}});
}

var embedCreate = function(col,des,tit) {
  return({embed: {color: col, title: tit,description: des}});
}

var cat = "http://random.cat/meow.php"

var servers = [];

function play(connection, message) {
  var server = servers[message.guild.id];

  server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(YTDL(server.queue[0],       {filter:"audioonly"}));

  server.queue.shift();

  server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
    if (server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
    else connection.disconnect();
  });
}
```

This is created every time the command is executed:

```
var server = servers[message.guild.id];
```

Comment: You're going to have to post more of your code for us to fully understand what's going on here. The issue is with however you're assigning the `server` variable.

Comment: I still don't see your 'problematic line': `if server.dispatcher server.dispatcher.end();` - please include the code around that line that you are having problems with

Comment: var server = servers[message.guild.id];

Do you have an array with the length of a snowflake id?